# Поддержка двусторонней связи

Tags: c#, wcf

Для реализации чата используется wsDualHttpBinding. Его время жизни ограничено. Логично, что для чата это очень важно. Можно запустить таймер на клиенте и обновлять соединение. Но слишком похоже на костыль. Есть ли другой вариант решения проблемы?

Comment: настройте reliableSession

Comment: Но, вообще говоря, выбор wsDualHttpBinding для чата очень странный. Не лучше ли использовать tcp биндинг или веб-сокеты?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, Вы имеете в виду netTcpBinding? Если да, то почему этот вариант лучше?

Comment: WCF считается устаревшей технологией (а жаль). Посмотрите в сторону SignalR. [Tutorial: Real-time chat with SignalR 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, SignalR - для Asp.Net. У меня же десктопное приложение

Comment: @АлександрПертенава хотя бы тем, что не требует открытых портов с двух сторон

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058856/5045688 - ничто не мешает использовать SignalR в десктопном приложении

Comment: @АлександрПертенава и да, клиентский SignalR не требует ASP.NET